# matching subreddit with submission with PRAW in Python

Tags: python, praw

I want to collect the stream of all reddit submissions with their corresponding subreddits. With the following structure: Column1 = subreddit ; column2 = submission title

I now have the following code, but I am unable to get the subreddits title.

```
for submission in reddit.subreddit('all').hot(limit=None):
print(subreddit.display_name)
```

How can I obtain the corresponding title?

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the subreddit the submission is being posted in, use the following:

```py
for submission in reddit.subreddit('all').hot(limit=None):
    print(submission.subreddit)
```